# Admin Notification Magento 2

Tags: adminhtml, grid

I am working on admin notification area where I want to show on message which is related to currently logged-in user.
I have created a column in db with user_id  where after some functionally I push message with specific userID.
now I want that when that specific user logged in he see all messages where

> userId == currentLoggedInUserID

adminhtml_notification_block.xml this is the layout file where the collection file is placed.
Now, when I create my custom collection file and extend the protected function

> _initSelect()

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $currentUserId =  $this->adminSession->getUser()->getId();
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->addFieldToFilter('brand_user', $currentUserId);
        $this->addRemoveFilter();
        return $this;
```

it throws a NULL error because I can not get the session of the admin user in the collection file. what is the suggestion for this, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can open the Observer folder, it has one function.

```php
if ($this->_backendAuthSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $feedModel = $this->_feedFactory->create();
            /* @var $feedModel \Magento\AdminNotification\Model\Feed */
            $feedModel->checkUpdate();
        }
```

In `isLoggedIn`, you will see the code for getting the current user's id. You can use this in your collection.

The code you provided is not complete, no one know what your adminSession is so next time try to provide the needed information.